Create Batch Operation on AWS S3 Glacier object with SSE-C
Is it possible to performer batch operation on an object in AWS S3 Glacier that is encrypted with SSE-C?
The operation is to call restore for the object.
I try to run batch operation and it work correctly for non-encrypted object with SSE-C.

Did you try it? Did it work? Or did you receive an error? I would think that you can restore the object, but you would not be able to read the contents unless you provide the matching encryption key.
